# How to extract the value from matrix cell without "subscript out of bounds" error?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have my.data matrix which consist of 32 columns and about 23000 rows. I want to extract particular value of cells from 10 and 20 columns, so I use a for-loop:

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(my.data)) {
  day <- as.numeric(my.data[i,10])
  night <- as.numeric(my.data[i,20])
  sum <- day+night
  if (sum > 2200 ) {
    my.data <- my.data [-i,]
  }
}
```

but the "Error in my.data[i, 10] : subscript out of bounds" is shown. Can you explain me what is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative indexes remove elements, therefore your `my.data` matrix becomes smaller while `i` will still try to access all rows which were present in your original data.

```
> matrix(1:9, 3,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> matrix(1:9, 3,3)[-1,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
> x <- matrix(1:9, 3,3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> x[-1, ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
>
```

try:

```
i <- 1
while (i <= nrow(my.data)) {
  day <- as.numeric(my.data[i,10])
  night <- as.numeric(my.data[i,20])
  sum <- day+night
  if (sum > 2200 ) {
    my.data <- my.data [-i,]
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```

UPDATE:
or use a more `R` like solution:

```
row_idx <- ( as.numeric(my.data[, 10]) + 
             as.numeric(my.data[, 20]) ) <= 2200
my.data <- my.data[row_idx, ]
```